# SwipeRefreshLayout for RecycleView for both top and bottom?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView,I want it to be SwipeRefreshLayout when pull from top,so I can get the latest 20 item and show it at RecyclerView.At the same time,when reach the 20th item at the bottom,then fetch another 20th item from the database.

Therefore,I get the last item like below,so I can fetch the next 20th item.

```
//for endless scroll
    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            visibleItemCount = recyclerView.getChildCount();
            totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
            firstVisibleItem = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

            if (loading) {
                if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
                    loading = false;
                    previousTotal = totalItemCount;
                }
            }
            if (!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount)
                    <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
                // End has been reached

                Log.i("Yaeye!", "end called");
                fetchPost(feedItems.get(feedItems.size()-1).getId());
                //This function is fetch the next 20th item from database




                // Do something

                loading = true;
            }
        }
    });

}
```

This is alright when it reach the bottom of the Recycleview,but the problem is when now is the top(1st item in RecyclerView),I pull down,suppose it fetch the new item,but it crashed.This is the error:

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=27; index=-1

**Here is my code:** for the `SwipeRefreshLayout` to fetch latest 20th item in database

```
// show loader and fetch messages
    swipeRefreshLayout.post(
            new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    clear();
                    fetchIntialPost(); // this one,fetch the latest item
                }
            }
    );
```

So I know that it cause by,when at the 1st item,it also consider the end of the RecyclerView,so it call `fetchPost(feedItems.get(feedItems.size()-1).getId());` this function instead of this function `fetchIntialPost();`

So now my question is,when at the top(1st item),call `fetchIntialPost();` when pull the `SwipeRefreshLayout` down?and the last item,just call `fetchPost(feedItems.get(feedItems.size()-1).getId());` .

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by checking the value of `feedItems.size()-1` before execute this line of code `fetchPost(feedItems.get(feedItems.size()-1).getId());`

Here is my working code :

```
//top and bottom also consider end of the list
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            visibleItemCount = recyclerView.getChildCount();
            totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
            firstVisibleItem = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
            lastVisibleItem = mLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();

            if (loading) {
                if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
                    loading = false;
                    previousTotal = totalItemCount;
                }
            }
            if (!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount)
                    <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
                // End has been reached
                //top and bottom also consider end of the list
                Log.i("Yaeye!", "end called");
                if(feedItems.size() - 1 > 0) {
                    //when pull down SwipeRefreshLayout,feedItems.size = -1
                    //so if greater than 0,means is bottom of the list
                    // Do something
                    fetchPost(feedItems.get(feedItems.size() - 1).getId());

                    loading = true;
                }else{
                  //here is the top of the list
                }
            }

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
lastVisibleItem = mLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();

if (!loading && lastVisibleItem == (totalItemCount - 1)) {
  // End has been reached
}
```

Comment: this one is not crashed,but when at the bottom it cant call `fetchPost(feedItems.get(feedItems.size()-1).getId());` simply didnt call this function

Comment: Can you kindly observe the value of loading, lastVisibleItem and totalItemCount when bottom is reached?

Comment: I `log.d` out,when 1st item I pull down,no value come out and crashed,when I at bottom,it keep loading..

Comment: When the list is reached to the bottom the lastVisibleItem position must the 1 less then the totalItem count. so `lastVisibleItem == (totalItemCount - 1)` must be true. But for some reason the value of `loading` variable is true and the `if` statement is becoming false.